# Batch Script to wait for program to close by user before applying msi update

Tags: batch-file, wait

I'm using a network management tool to apply updates to software and I have an issue where if a users is already using the program you want to update the update will fail as you would expect.
I have been trying to put together a batch script that will detect whether the the program is running and if it is the script will **wait until the user closes down the program** and the apply the msi update.

I've pretty much scoured google but can only really find previous scripts that kill the program first before proceeding and I don't want that to happen as the user may lose work.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

    start "" notepad.exe

:loop
    (tasklist | find /i "notepad.exe" && ( ping -n 2 localhost & goto loop)) >nul 

    echo Notepad closed
```

This just starts notepad.exe (the running program) and waits until it is closed. Adapt according to your needs

Comment: That works a treat, I didn't need the 'start "" notepad.exe' bit though because that just runs the program, but the loop works great. Thanks!

Comment: Just for clarity this is what I ended up using...
_@echo off

:loop
    tasklist | find /i "notepad.exe" > nul && ( ping -n 2 localhost & goto loop) >nul 

    echo Notepad closed

msiexec /I update.msi_

Comment: @Jamman, I was using notepad as a sample of a program in a running state, to have someting to wait for, and instead of starting the program and then the batch file to monitor if it is running, i just started it from the same batch. So, the `start ...` SHOULD not be in your code, but what you MUST do is to change the string that the `find` command is using to whatever your program is.

Comment: Yup I was just using notpad.exe as a test too, the real exe is revit.exe so I will just replace the find notepad.exe with revit.exe
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
`tasklist |find "programname"`
```

will tell you if the programm is running:

```
if %errorlevel%==0 echo running
```

put just a little loop around it:

```
:loop
tasklist |find "programname" >nul
if %errorlevel%==0 (
  echo prgram running
  timeout 2>nul
  goto loop
)
echo program not running
```