# Wait till one program is finished before starting next in Windows Script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, windows-7

I have to found **uninstallers** in all the subdirectories inside a specified directory. Once the **uninstaller** is found then, I need to run it.

```
@setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@for /r %%i in ( un*.exe) do (
        @echo Found file: %%~nxi            

        %%i             
        )
```

I am already able to search the subdirectories and find the uninstallers inside them using the code above.

**PROBLEM:** The command `%%i` executes the `uninstaller.exe` and the control immediately returns to the command prompt. Due to the immediate return of control to the command prompt, the next iteration of `for-loop` is executed and therefore the next uninstaller (by command `%%i`) is also started.

**What I need:** I want to stay in the current iteration of `for-loop` till the uninstaller started by the command `%%i` is finished.

**PS:** The uninstaller programs do not finish by themselves. They ask for a couple of options and therefore, I want to start them one by one (so that user doesn't get confused).

**PS-2:** As pointed out in one of the comments below that PowerShell can solve the issue so, I am looking for more suggestions from PowerShell community as well.

Comment: In general, this may not be solvable. Whilst you should be able to wait for the program you've launched to exit, there's no guarantee that it doesn't accomplish its job by launching *another* process or scheduling some activity in the OS, either of which could outlive the lifetime of that program you launched.

Comment: E.g. an uninstall program may just be a thin shim that just launches an appropriate `msiexec` process to perform the uninstall and then itself exits.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: In my case, the uninstaller asks for a couple of options and doesn't finish by itself once started.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, it's not easily solvable if we're restricted to a CMD script. But it's not generally a problem in other languages that make use of a Job object, such as PowerShell's `start-process` with the `wait` option.

Comment: @eryksun: I am flexible to use PowerShell if that can solve the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the powershell tag and add a statement that PowerShell answers are welcome. I won't add an answer since I'm not a PowerShell expert. I know it uses a Job object that doesn't allow silent breakaway, but I don't know whether it's implemented in a race-free way that involves creating the process in a suspended state, adding it to the Job, and then resuming it. If it instead adds the running process to the Job, then the child that the uninstaller creates may escape the Job.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you want to 1) find all files named `un*.exe` in a particular path and its subdirectories, 2) execute each one, and 3) wait for each executable to complete before executing the next one, you can write something like this in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Uninstaller Path\un*.exe" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
  Start-Process $_ -Wait
}
```

Comment: I stepped through this with a debugger, and while it creates the process suspended, it actually calls `ResumeThread` before it calls `AssignProcessToJobObject`. That's wrong, and someone on the PowerShell team should fix it. That said, I built a test executable that immediately spawns another process and exits. The grandchild process didn't escape the Job in 10 repeated tests. One caveat is that the OP is using Windows 7, which doesn't allow nested Job objects, so in Windows 7, PowerShell itself shouldn't be assigned to a Job (e.g. the Task Scheduler runs tasks in a Job).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `start /wait`. Compare the following two lines:

```
for %%i in (*.txt) do notepad "%%i"

for %%i in (*.txt) do start /wait notepad "%%i"
```

The first one will open all matching files in several Notepads, the second one will only open the next Notepad, when you close the previous one.

Comment: I already tried to use `start` but then it throws an error `Windows cannot find C:\Program`. The type of file I want to start is `.exe`. I also tried to use `start "" %%i` but that also did not work.

Comment: That's because of the space in the path. The Quotes cure that. This is just an example of how to do it. In case of EXEs, of course use `start /wait "" "%%i"` (the empty string `""` is a pseudo title, because `start` takes the first quoted argument as a title)

Comment: Waiting is the *default* behavior when running a program in a batch script. It doesn't matter whether it's a GUI or console program. That only matters at the interactive prompt. Most of the time `start` is actually used to *avoid waiting*. The `/wait` option is required if you need some other feature of `start` (e.g. window state, CPU affinity) but still want to wait for the program to exit.

Comment: Just now, I tried `start /wait "" "%%i"` but the problem is still there (i.e. both the .exe start).

Comment: @eryksun: I know that statement, but it's not always true. Try my example. both: some EXEs do, some don't.

Comment: @skm if that doesn't work, you have to use something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23008242/2152082)

Comment: No, in a batch script `for %%i in (*.txt) do notepad "%%i"` waits for each notepad instance to exit.

Comment: @eryksun: indeed - *in a batch file* it waits, *on command line*, it doesn't. `:/`

Comment: @Stephan: Unfortunately that is not helpful for me. The file name of the uninstaller is `Uninstall.exe` but the image name (or program name) is different. So the script does not find it running. Moreover, I tried to use your script but it does not enter in the `for-loop` second time.

Comment: no `goto` and no labels inside a `for` loop - they break the loop!. `Call` a subroutine instead.

Comment: @eryksun, just as an example what @Stephan is trying to tell you (under Windows 7): `calc.exe` returns immediately, but `start /WAIT "" calc.exe` does not...

Comment: @aschipfl, no in a batch script CMD waits for the (classic) calc.exe if `start` isn't used, just like it waits for everything program that it runs in a *script*. The new Windows 10 calc.exe "app" is very different and more like the OP's present problem with a program that launches another process or passes the request to an already running instance and then immediately exits. Anyway, this answer is just wrong. It's written as a script (escape percent for loop variable) and then makes a claim that is completely false for batch scripts. And it's of no help with the OP's problem anyway.

Comment: @eryksun, I meant in command prompt, I should have mentioned that, sorry for confusion...

Comment: CMD's interactive prompt has run GUI apps without waiting since at least the NT port and maybe even in OS/2. It gets the address of the child's PEB from `NtQueryInformationProcess` and reads it via `ReadProcessMemory`. This is public information. However, then it uses the undocumented offset of the `ImageSubsystem` field (GUI is 2 and console is 3), which only Microsoft can reliably use since it's free to change most internal details of the PEB between Windows versions (i.e. the *documented* structure is mostly generic and useless fields like `BYTE Reserved11[128]`, etc).